# Highlight user's country when first accepts geolocation and then remove when other countries are selected (Leafletjs)

Tags: javascript, plugins

I am a newbie here so please bear with me. I am trying to use L.countrySelect plugin to control the maps whereby when the user chooses a country from a dropdown list, the corresponding country will show up as highlighted and zoomed in.

The problem I am facing is that the first country (user's country) isn't highlighted when the app is first opened and the user allows geolocation detection. When I managed to get the user country to highlight, the highlight refuses to be removed when a different country is selected. The country gets a double highlight when I choose the same country as the user from the dropdown list.

I have the standard Leaflet.countrySelect.js file that is on Github and my main.js code are as follows:

main.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{attribution: 'Tiles &copy; CartoDB'});
var map = L.map("map",{layers: [baseLayer], center: [50.38, -0.06], zoom: 4});
//var select = L.countrySelect({include:"French Southern and Antarctic Lands"});

let countryLayer = null;

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    const lat = position.coords.latitude;
    const lng = position.coords.longitude;

    const apiKey = 'abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz1234567890';    
    const url = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${lat}+${lng}&key=${apiKey}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const country = data.results[0].components.country;
        const countryCode = data.results[0].components["ISO_3166-1_alpha-2"];
        console.log(country, countryCode);
        
        });
    }, function(){
      console.log('Geolocation failed');
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Geolocation not supported');
  }

  
$.getJSON('countries.geo.json').done(function(data){
  var select = L.countrySelect(data);
        select.addTo(map);

      select.on('change', function(e) {
        if (e.feature === undefined) {
            return;
        }
      var country = L.geoJson(e.feature);
      if (this.previousCountry != null) {
         map.removeLayer(this.previousCountry);
       } else {
        map.addLayer(country);
       } 
      this.previousCountry = country;  
       map.addLayer(country);
      map.fitBounds(country.getBounds());
   });
 });
})
```

index.html

```
The usual html code with just this below to create the map Layer

<div id="map" class="map leaflet-container">
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in anticipation!

I tried this but it does not work either.

```
getCurrentCountry();
//get user's coordinates using geolocation

function getCurrentCountry() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {

    function successCallback(position) {
      const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(`Latitude: ${latitude}, Longitude: ${longitude}`);
    
  //get more information about current location
  //getCurrentCountry(latitude, longitude);
    }

    // Define an error callback function
    function errorCallback(error) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          console.error("User denied the request for geolocation.");
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          console.error("Location information is unavailable.");
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          console.error("The request to get user location timed out.");
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          console.error("An unknown error occurred.");
          break;
      }
    }
    // Request the user's current location
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
  } else {
    // Geolocation is not available in this browser
    console.error("Geolocation is not supported in this browser.");
  }
}
})

function setCurrentLocationInMap() {
        
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCurrentCountry, setDefaultCountry, options);
  } else {
      setDefaultCountry();
  }
}
```